# Display PHP Array values outside 'for loop'

Tags: php, html, arrays, function

Here is my code

```
for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["Parameter_length"]; $i++)
{
  echo "Eqt_Param".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]; 
}
```

The above code will display

```
Eqt_Param0=2.00
Eqt_Param1=3.00
Eqt_Param2=1.00
Eqt_Param3=5.00
```

If I put `echo()` outside the for loop, I need the same result. Please help me to fix this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? Simply concatenating the result of the foreach into a variable which can be echoed.

```
$output = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $Percentile["Parameter_length"]; $i++)
{
    $output .= "Eqt_Param" . $i . "=" . $Percentile["Eqt_Param" . $i];
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your values in a viarable that exists outside of the scope of the `for`
like:

```
$accumulatedString = '';
for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["Parameter_length"]; $i++) { 
  echo "Eqt_Param".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]; 
  $accumulatedString .= "Eqt_Param".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i];
}
echo $accumulatedString;
```

Thats if you want it all as one string.